# What causes variations in x/y (Left/Top) positions between devices?

Tags: basic4android

I've noticed that hard coded Top/left positions (gathered via code) from the avd do not correspond to the same points on my android device.

Basically I have a map image as a panel with another panel containing a position indicator (like x marks the spot)  works fine in the avd, but there is a significant offset on the phone I'm using to test.  Concerned such hard coding will cause issues on other phones too.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 'dip' units (device independent pixel). For example:

```
Button1.Left = 30dip
```

By using 'dip' units the actual value is scaled based on the device scale.

Comment: That worked very nicely.   Can "dip" be added to a string ie "300dip" or is it just called as DipToCurrent("300") <br/> Dim xPos as String <br/> xPos = "300dip" <br> Button.Left = xPos

Comment: Why would you want to add dip to a string? It only applies to numbers.

Comment: an aray of left,top positions to create pointer travel on a map.    Example 100dip,110dip 110dip,100dip 120dip,100dip   Does that make any sense?  I got the array to work using 100,110... and then added the DipToCurrent(... but I was curious if I had to call this every time I converted it or if I could just add the dip to the array

Comment: You can add 'dip' to any number.